# Mysqli Prepared statement with a mysql variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a sql query that returns 5 closest locations using latitude & longitude.

```
$conn->query("SELECT activityId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
 -0.0761144) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.longitude ) - radians(

  51.5080937) ) + sin( radians(
  -0.0761144) ) * sin( radians(
    activity.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from activity order by distance limit 5;");
```

I need to make this a prepared statement, but to use the ? placeholder doesn't make sense as it would mean binding the same param twice. Oh and it doesn't actually work.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT activityId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
 ?) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.longitude ) - radians(

  ?) ) + sin( radians(
  ?) ) * sin( radians(
    activity.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from activity order by distance limit 5;");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("ddd", $lat, $lng, $lat);
```

So I've done a little research and from what I can gather using a variable in the mysql statement seems the best approach, but this is where i get stuck, so far I have as follows.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("

set @lat = ?;
set @lng = ?;    

SELECT activityId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
 @lat) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(
  activity.longitude ) - radians(

  @lng) ) + sin( radians(
  @lat) ) * sin( radians(
    activity.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from activity order by distance limit 5;

");

$stmt->bind_param("dd", $lat, $lng");
```

However now the params don't bind and I get a error response back stating this. I've had a look on google and the answer I have been directed towards consists of running two queries, the font creating the variables as just a query() then then SELECT statement in a second prepared statement. But surely then the statements are not being prepared and leaves the query open to SQL Injection?

Is there a better way to prepare this statement so it's secure from injection attacks?

//* EDIT *//

After some great answers it seems that using set @var isn't valid in $sql->prepare(); I guess I can now refine the question to be; How can I run this as a prepared statement?:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT activityId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
?) ) * cos( radians(
activity.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(
activity.longitude ) - radians(

?) ) + sin( radians(
?) ) * sin( radians(
activity.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from activity order by distance limit 5;");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("ddd", $lat, $lng, $lat);
```

Comment: I assume it's a typo, but there is a `"` in the last line that shouldn't be there: `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $lat, $lng");`

Comment: Not sure that mysqli supports named parameters; PDO does, but I'm not seeing equivalent information in the mysqli manual. Your parameters are valid SQL, just not valid for use in `prepare/bind_param`

Comment: Sidenote: You're repeating `$lat` in `$stmt = $conn->prepare("sss", $lat, $lng, $lat);` - If that works but not for the other, then do the same for the other.

Comment: @ipg yer sorry that's a typo

Comment: @fred -li- I've tried it with two, and with three like on the example (matching the amount of ?). However neither approach seems to work.

Comment: Ah @Tieson T That would be why then, which I guess moves me back to the second example. I'm however still a little stuck on the correct way of doing this.

Comment: The correct way is the first way you did it ... sure it repeats the variable... but who really cares?  There isn't some coding standard out there that says when you use the same variable multiple times you have to use some kind of string interpolation for clarity.  Anyone who comes after you and looks at this code will know exactly what you did.  If they come after you and look at the crazy stuff you had to do to get named replacements, they'll cock their heads to the side and curse your name.  Stick with the simple solution that works and is easily manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT activityId, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(
?) ) * cos( radians(
activity.latitude ) ) * cos( radians(
activity.longitude ) - radians(

?) ) + sin( radians(
?) ) * sin( radians(
activity.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from activity order by distance limit 5;");

$stmt->bind_param("ddd", $lat, $lng, $lat);
$result = $stmt->execute();
if($result){
  echo 'SELECT succesful';
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try setting the type to double?

```
$stmt->bind_param("dd", $lat, $lng);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on here, being set as a double doesn't make any difference.